# How exactly does Properties Service work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So what I did previously is when I make functions to call them, I would make variables of the same value, which is `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getActiveSheet();`, and someone suggested/required me to save the sheet as a named property instead and keep calling it in the functions instead of making like 100 of same variables with the exact same values.

I watched the videos on Youtube and stuff - tried this out:

```
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var sheetID = "1dRAXZRHMgfR_oX1ZF1RFeonUi7ZPk_wbRf7Jx0UvCjE";
documentProperties.setProperties('spreadsheetID', sheetID);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentProperties.getProperty(spreadsheetID)).getActiveSheet();
var logsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentProperties.getProperty(spreadsheetID)).getSheetByName("Log");
documentProperties.setProperties('timesheet', sheet);
documentProperties.setProperties('logsheet',log);
```

So I need to be able to call the variables sheet and logsheet in all other functions - if I have these at function `onOpen()`, will I be able to do that by just simply using `documentProperties.getProperties(timesheet)` or `documentProperties(logsheet)`?

Comment: [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, you can't call them as a function `documentProperties(logsheet)`. The correct way is `documentProperties.getProperty('logsheet')`.

You can use them as some kind of global variables, but you are using the wrong methods:

```
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var spreadsheetID = '1dRAXZRHMgfR_oX1ZF1RFeonUi7ZPk_wbRf7Jx0UvCjE'
  documentProperties.setProperty('spreadsheetID', spreadsheetID);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentProperties.getProperty('spreadsheetID')).getActiveSheet();
  var logsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentProperties.getProperty('spreadsheetID')).getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  documentProperties.setProperty('timesheet', sheet);
  documentProperties.setProperty('logsheet',log);
```

[SetProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperties(Object)), in plural,  is to set multiple properties:

```
 documentProperties.setProperties{timesheet: sheet, logsheet: log};
```

Keep in mind that [Properties cannot be shared between scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties), so you can only use those within the scripts of the same project, but yes, you can use them in an `onOpen()` function as any regular variable. To make sure you are getting the values you want, put a `Logger.log(documentProperties.getProperties())` at the end of the code.

Comment: Honestly, I am still confused about how the system works. After looking at the response, I added the codes documentProperties.setProperty('timesheet', sheet) and ('logsheet', log) in the function onOpen(), and now I am not sure how I can use getProperty() in other functions to get the value I stored in onOpen().

Comment: Do I need to call documentProperties as a parameter for other functions in order to use the variable timesheet & logsheet or can I just straight away use  documentProperties.getProperty('logsheet') in the other functions?

Comment: Yes, you have to access them using `documentProperties.getProperty('logsheet')` from any script, but you have to declare `var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();` first in every script you want to use them.