# How can I share configurations among all users in a domain-wide installed GMAIL/GSuite Addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have been studying GMAIL Addon development lately. I would like admins, subscribing to my GMAIL addon, to be able to upload a configuration file in their domain which my addon can consume later when they are installed by the users under the same domain.

This mechanism is pretty much like the chrome.storage feature for chrome extensions. In one of our extensions,  our client-admins upload a configuration file into their installed extension’s users settings and our extension downloads this data via chrome.storage apis.

Is the propertiesService the best way to go? Thank you.

Comment: How are you going to upload the configuration file? Because as stated in the propertiesService documentation [1] you have to set the values inside the script, can the other admins edit their version of the add-on/script? [1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service

Comment: Here is a question where it's more explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999367/how-exactly-does-properties-service-work

Comment: Thank you @AndresDuarte for the awesome comments. It seems like sharing data among all users under the same domain is not viable via Properties class. Does the GSuite addon APIs have an equivalent mechanism for "Chrome.storage" where domain level configurations can easily be obtained? Thank you in advance.